# offset UIimageview

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an image in my UIimageview and when I move the location of the View the image inside gets offset... for example I can have a  10x10 ImageView and a 10x10 Image inside then when I move the view the image is printed at -1, -1 of the View so it is clipped.  Any suggestions

here is the code

```
node2.frame = CGRectMake(nodex2-5, nodey2-5, 10, 10);
```

Comment: can you post the code that moves the `UIImageView`?

Comment: I edited the original post... you can find the code there

Comment: @King Popsicle: if this question is posted somewhere else in full then please remove this one or at least provide a link to the other question.

Comment: couldnt replicate ur error. how are you adding ur imageview???

Comment: More code, please, and accept some of your answers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience such problems often arise when using double data types for position variables.  For example, if nodex2 and nodey2 are floating point data type with non integer values the alignment of the image can change while sliding it around.  Switching the variables to integer types or casting them before passing into CGRectMake would solve the problem if this is your issue.